# Is there a way to turn JSON data into a nested array using for loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, for-loop, nested

I am trying to display the data (a bunch of upcoming events) on list.php using JavaScript, I think a for loop is the way to go but am not sure what is wrong with this. The console displays nothing, previously I had my for loop outside of the xhttp.onreadystatechange and it was giving "getData is undeclared" error messages. I am very new to this so apologies if I worded the question wrong or am not clear. I am a beginner coder so please no overly complicated answers!

here is my list.php code:

```
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        function getData() {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    var javaobj = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
                    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = javaobj.name + " " + 
javaobj.date + " " + javaobj.time + " " + javaobj.location + " " + javaobj.organiser;
                }
                xhttp.open("GET", "events.json", true);
                xhttp.send();
                //for loop to go split javaobj into array elements             
                for (i = 0; i < javaobj.length; ++i) {
                    console.log(javaobj[i].name);
                    console.log(javaobj[i].date);
                    console.log(javaobj[i].time);
                    console.log(javaobj[i].location);
                    console.log(javaobj[i].organiser);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" name="data" onclick="getData()" value="Click to View Events" />
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: look into using [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) api.. `fetch('events.json').then(res => res.json()).then(console.log)`

Comment: The `onreadystatechange` [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) almost certainly [doesn't fire when you think it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState), and as the previous commenter suggested, you should be using the fetch API, avoiding `XMLHttpRequest` entirely.